# Is there a way to put some images in an array (values)?

Tags: java, android, android-viewpager

I have created an activity with a viewPager and 5 fragments with 5 differents colors. Each views must a have its own color and its own picture.
For the colors, I put my colors ressources in an array. Each view have a number position then numberposition = array position = color. Works fine.

But How can I do for the pictures?

Comment: What's the source of your images? Base64? Raw? Drawable?

Comment: they are in drawable @jackz314

Answer (score -1, accepted):

yes you can put your images inside the `drawable` folder and inside your Activity
you can use put your images inside the array this way:

```
int[] images = {R.drawable.imageone,R.drawable.imagetwo,R.drawable.imagethree};
```

and to set the drawable for imageview

```
ImageView mainImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
//set the first image
mainImage.setImageResource(images[0]);
```

Comment: thank you, now i have to put it in my pageAdapter method args

Comment: @AceKtp please give me +1 on my answer and mark it as correct

Comment: Not enought reputation, I cannot @André